# how to store nokogiri data in an empty array to later be called on

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface, nokogiri

Im creating a ruby cli app that uses nokogiri to scrape li elements from a webpage. right now my application returns them as a block of li's. How can I separate these, store them in an array to be called upon when a user enters a number?
in my cli.rb i have,

```
def more
    input_prompt = "Enter a number between 1-42 for a random plant fact, or type 'exit' to leave:"
    puts input_prompt
    input = nil
    while input != "exit"
      input = gets.strip.to_i
        return facts
     if input == "exit"
        puts exit
      else
        puts "Sorry, I didn't understand that. #{input_prompt}" 
      end
    end
end
```

and in my scraper I have

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.funfactsabout.net/plant-facts/"))
doc.css("ul.facts-list li").text
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
def fact(number)
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open("https://www.funfactsabout.net/plant-facts/"))
  node_set = doc.css("ul.facts-list")
  array_of_facts = node_set.children.map(&:text) - ["\n"]
  
  if number > array_of_facts.size
    puts "No fact under number #{number}"
  else
    puts array_of_facts[number-1]  # array indexing begins with 0
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you! that still returns as a block of text rather than a single li associated with a number that can be called upon.

Comment: @zswqa I think it returns you an array of facts. Kiana's code returns you an array where you can use the user's number input to get the fact using index. I assume that is what you are trying here. Please tell me if my understanding about your problem is wrong.

Comment: @Kiana to better understand your app's expected output, provide example how you see it.

Comment: @NaveenHonestRaj yes it returns array of facts and every fact can be accessed by index (= input) that is provided by user.

Comment: my return is currently```Hi! do you like plants?[yes/no]:
yes
Would you like some plant fun facts?[yes/no]
yes
Enter a number between 1-42 for a random plant fact, or type 'exit' to leave:
3
An average size tree can provide enough wood to make 170,100 pencils.
The first type of aspirin, painkiller and fever reducer came from the tree bark of a willow tree.
85% of plant life is found in the ocean.(more facts listed...) I want to have only a single one returned when a number is typed in